# Will Underscore.js defaults() set a property if its defined on a prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype, underscore.js

Create objects `m` and `n` where `m` is the prototype of `n`:

```
var m, n;

m = {beep: 'boop'};
n = Object.create(m);
```

`n.beep` is `'boop'` because its set on the prototype `m`.

`_(n).has('beep')` is `false` 'cause its not an 'own' property.

Now if we default `n.beep` to `'blip'`:

```
_.defaults(n, {beep: 'blip'});
```

will it stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `n.beep` is still `'boop'`.  [Fiddle it](http://jsfiddle.net/EFEwg/embedded/) or check the [annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-79).